# Azure Postgres & Query Performance Insight: Query text not showing

Tags: postgresql, azure

I have enabled `Query Performance Insights`, however, the `Query Text` fields are left empty, as you can see from the screenshot below.

[image]

I have enabled the `Query Store` as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-query-store), everything else has been left to its default values.

- `pg_qs.query_capture_mode` is set to `TOP`
- `pgms_wait_sampling.query_capture_mode` is set to `ALL`

If I query the `query_store.qs_view` or `pgms_wait_sampling_view` data is returned.

```
SELECT * FROM query_store.qs_view;
SELECT * FROM query_store.pgms_wait_sampling_view;
```

Also the column `qs_view.query_sql_text` contains SQL statements, as well as the `query_texts_view`. Any idea why its not showing up in the UI?

Answer (score 0):

In the portal page of your Azure Database for PostgreSQL server, select Query performance Insight under the Intelligent Performance section of the menu bar. Query Text is no longer supported is shown. However, the query text can still be viewed by connecting to azure_sys and querying 'query_store.query_texts_view'.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-query-performance-insight